# caputure event when user expands the notification bar

Tags: android, events, notifications

is there any way to capture or intercept the event when user expands the notification bar.

 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry. For starters, there will not be a "notification bar" on some devices, such as Google TV devices.